# How to set the app:tabBackground of a tabLayout programmatically?

Tags: android

This is my code: It's a tabLayout that I `setupWith` a `Viewpager`

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="-1dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabPaddingStart="-1dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText" />
```

But how do I set this programmatically?

```
 app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
```

It is really important to set this tabBackground programmatically because I want the color to change depending on the theme that the user has chose

These are what I've already tried but none of them is working:

```
    tabLayout.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
    tabLayout.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
    tabLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
    tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
```

**Note:**

This is my tab_color_selector.xml in drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue_alu" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 11):

Try this.

```
ViewGroup tabStrip = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View tabView = tabStrip.getChildAt(i);
    if (tabView != null) {
        int paddingStart = tabView.getPaddingStart();
        int paddingTop = tabView.getPaddingTop();
        int paddingEnd = tabView.getPaddingEnd();
        int paddingBottom = tabView.getPaddingBottom();
        ViewCompat.setBackground(tabView, AppCompatResources.getDrawable(tabView.getContext(), tabViewBgResId));
        ViewCompat.setPaddingRelative(tabView, paddingStart, paddingTop, paddingEnd, paddingBottom);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the only solution that worked for me!!!

```
binding.tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
    override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
    override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}


    override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
     tab.view.background = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(requireContext().resources,  R.drawable.tab_color_selector, null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the selected tab background you can use this:
(Set your custom view after set up the viewPager)

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);    
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()).setCustomView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

If you want to change the tabLayout background use this:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.your_drawable));
```

If you're using API level > 21 use it without ContextCompat like this:

```
tabLayout.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.badge));
```

Example:

**Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/Toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/Toolbar.Popup" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

---

**Drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I am trying to set a drawable as a background, not a color

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't work. the background I am trying to set programmatically is a tabBackground, your code is for normal background

Comment: I tried this code in my project and it works, can you put your drawable?

Comment: You want to change the background of tabLayout or the background of every tab?

Comment: I am the selected tab to highlighted

Comment: I added the way to change only the background of a tab

Comment: I'm using selectors for the tabs, e.g. the android:tabBackground xml attribute, which I can seem to be able to set. May have to rethink my choice.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved to change the "`app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"`" programmatically by doing this:

(My `tab_color_selector` and `second_tab_color_selector` are like yours (a selector with a color for the default and one for the selected)

The TabLayout XML:

```
    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabDots"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />
```

Then in `onCreate`:

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerFragments, true);
setupViewPager(viewPagerFragments);
```

I added a `TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener`:

```
viewPagerFragments.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout) {

      @Override
      public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch (position) {
          case 0:
            //Here my background is white so I need grey dots
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            break;

          case 1:
            //Here my background is also white so I need grey dots
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_color_selector));
            break;

          case 2:
            //Here my background is grey so I need white dots
            tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.second_tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.second_tab_color_selector));
            tabLayout.getTabAt(position).setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.second_tab_color_selector));
            break;
        }
      }

    });
```

Because doing this changed my "dots" layout I add to set a fixed `width` (`android:layout_width="50dp"` in my TabLayout XML).

I have NPE warnings on all `tabLayout.getTabAt(X).setIcon(....)` but because I know there are 3 tabs I allow myself to do this... (Maybe a better solution with a `for` ?)

Hope this will help someone

**---EDIT 1---**

I tested on API 28, 27 and 19 and it looks like it is not working on my emulators API 27... Will try something else and on a real device.

**---EDIT 2---**

Response from Ankur should be the accepted one... Works like a charm on all my emulators and is faster.

Answer (score 1):

just use custom layout for tab, here is working example:

put these two methods in to PagerAdapter

```
   fun initTabsView(parent: TabLayout) {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    (0 until count).forEach { i ->
        val tab: TabLayout.Tab? = parent.getTabAt(i)
        tab?.customView = getTabView(layoutInflater, i)
    }
}

private fun getTabView(layoutInflater: LayoutInflater, position: Int): View {
    val binding = TabCasinoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    binding.category = categories[position]
    return binding.root
}
```

and initTabsView(parent: TabLayout)  where you are initialising PagerAdapter itself

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Field field;
try {
    field = tabLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTabBackgroundResId");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(tabLayout, R.drawable.tab_background);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this i had two types of background for a tablayout. Based on the size of tab count it will modify the result

```
Field field;
    try {
        field = tabLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("tabBackgroundResId");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        if(tabLayout.getTabCount()>=3){
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
            field.set(tabLayout, R.drawable.tab_color_selector_two);
        } else {
            field.set(tabLayout, R.drawable.tab_color_selector);
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        Logger.e("TabError",e.getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

First Create a Tab selector:

// Tab selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected" 
android:state_selected="true"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"></item>
</selector>
```

// tab_indicator_slected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thickness="4dp"

android:useLevel="false">

<solid android:color="@color/intro_pink"></solid>
```

// Tab Indicator default

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadius="0dp" 
android:thickness="4dp" android:useLevel="false"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/white"></solid>
</shape>
```

add you ViewPager with Tab Layout adapter inside your Layout

```
 <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_100"
            android:visibility="visible"></androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp">

        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

//onCreate

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewPager vp = findViewById(R.id.vp_pager);
    TabLayout tb = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tb.setupWithViewPager(vp);
```

//add this only if the tb.setupWithViewPager(vp) didn't work perfectly

```
    vp.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                  tb.getTabAt(position).select();

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
}
```