# how to show tablayout background colour in android (each tab should be different colour when click the tab)

Tags: android, tabs

1. As bellow code indicate three Tab ,
2. i want to change the tab colour when perticular tab click
3. i tried all the setting background colour and also i follow all  answer , but it is not helpfull
4. please give me any solution for this.
   i want to show the tab colour should be different when clicking the tab

```js
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
          tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // setting colour but its not working 

          recyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bghomeback);
          titleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          titleText1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        
          ContentfulAdapter.getInstance().filter("");
          mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mSearchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mSearchText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mFavText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(storyFragment::requestSync);
          swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1) {
          titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          titleText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         
         // mRelative.setBackgroundResource(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
          tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));



          recyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seraback);
          ContentfulAdapter.getInstance().filter("");
          mSearchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          mFavText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
          swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
          swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2){
         
          recyclerView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favback);
          tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(R.drawable.taitemselect1);
          titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          titleText1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          //  mSearchImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mSearchText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          mSearchView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//          ContentfulAdapter.getInstance().filter("");
//          swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(storyFragment::requestSync);

          mFavText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          mFavText.setText("The books you mark as favourite will appear in this page.\n No favourite book added.");
          ContentfulAdapter.getInstance().showFavoriteItem();
          if (ContentfulAdapter.getInstance().getItemCount() < 1) {
            mFavText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mFavText.setText("The books you mark as favourite will appear in this page.\n No favourite book added.");
          } else {
            mFavText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

          }

          swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
          swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

**ISSUE**

The reason why this code isn't working is that actually you are not changing the tab background but the color of the indicator of the selected tab

**SOLUTION**

Since I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve, I'll give you some useful information about TabLayout.

The method `TabLayout.getTabCount()` returns the number of tabs in your Layout;

the method `TabLayout.getTabAt()` returns an object of type `TabLayout.Tab` that represents the tab.

With these two methods you can iterate over all the tabs and use the method `TabLayout.Tab.setCustomView(int)` or `TabLayout.Tab.setCustomView(View)` to use a custom view for that tab, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42535394/how-to-set-the-apptabbackground-of-a-tablayout-programatically) in the answer of MarcGV.

If you want a more dynamic solution you can use `TabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition()` to get the index of the selected tab and get the Tab object with the method mentioned before.

If you need to change just the color of each tab you can try to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
   TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
   tab.getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(getRandomColor()));
}
```

I assume that the method `getRandomColor()` picks one value from 000000 to FFFFFF.

Comment: But please note that the third line really depends on what you have inside the Tabs. For example, if you're using TabLayout with fragments you have to get the view of the fragment. To achieve this take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31890843/get-fragment-by-tag-or-id-from-tablayout-android)

Comment: thanks it is working ,,, but after click another tab the colour is same for previous tabbut i want to remove that coulor

Comment: No,, its not working , My requirement is i have 4 tab i need to add different colour for each tab when i click

Comment: Ok so maybe you should try set background colour onCreateView() of your fragments. Have you already tried this?

Comment: To do this you have to do view.setBackgroundColor(Color) in fragment's onCreateView() after you have inflated your view of course

Comment: No its not working bro.....view.setBackgroundColor(Color) this is setting entire tab(4 tab) background color...